# PHP sending HTTP headers by default?

Tags: php, apache, http

I am working on a site written in PHP which I am running locally on my computer (via XAMPP), and everything is working fine.  However, when it's running on the actual webserver (also apache), occasionally it doesn't behave correctly, because it's sending additional HTTP headers that I didn't specify.  The two main ones are:

- On a script that redirects to another page, a **"Content-type: image/gif"** header is sent, which causes the browser to interpret as a (broken) image instead of performing the redirect.
- On two scripts that output files (one a regular text file, another a GZipped text file), it prints a **"Status: 404 Not Found"** in addition to everything else, which, in some browsers doesn't matter but others (Chrome, Firefox) interpret as an error.

What could be the cause of this?  Are there any PHP settings that cause certain headers to be sent automatically?  Does it have anything to do with file permissions, or maybe something in a .htdocs file?

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: One of your installations has output buffering enabled, therefore the additional header() calls succeed there. Your app contains them somewhere, PHP does not make them up on its own. You need to debug this yourself: too localized.

Answer (score 1):

php sends only one header

> Array ( [0] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5 )

also you can use this to view the headers that sent over by doing this.

`print_r(headers_list());`

you should check your script , if you sent any headers or used any configurations over .htacesss or changed anything in the httpd.conf